# Number Theory: Divisibilty

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Q: Prove that if a and b are positive integers satisfying (a,b)=[a,b}, then a=b.

My approach (with ans):
(a,b) means gcd, and I let g=(a,b)
since g is the gcd,
then I get these two: g|a and g|b, while g

Next is [a,b], the lcm of a and b, and I let it be h.
then I get another two of these: a|h and b|h while a

Combine the inequalities together will get:
g

Since the question provides that g=h,
so h

Is the a correct explanation? As I hope to get full credits, I hope I can present my answers as detail as possible (without any faults). Thank you.

Comment: `Combine the inequalities` *Which* inequalities? There is no inequality in the posted question. However, it would be enough to argue that $\,(a,b) \le a \le [a,b]\,$.

Comment: Oh, i may miss typing (a,b)≤a≤[a,b]. Thank you very much.